# Cyclic group of prime order

Tags: group-theory

If G be a cyclic group of prime order p, prove that every non identity element of G is a generator of the group.

Comment: what have you tried? this is a very standard problem that should be in pretty much any book on group theory.

Comment: what do you know about the order of the elements of the group G?

Comment: This is the fourth question you have asked in a very short time, and two of your previous ones have been closed asking for you to improve them. You have not answered any of the requests for further information or clarification on any of them, nor have shown any of your own work. **Please** read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Comment: Since G is cyclic there is an element a such that a^p=e and <a>=<a^k> if gcd(n,k)=1 since p is prime gcd(p,k) for any k is 1.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Using Lagrange's Theorem, what are *the possible* orders of subgroups, and also of elements, of $\;G\;$ ?

So then...

Comment: can you illustrate it more??

Comment: Can you write down Lagrange's theorem, one of the most basic, elementary theorems in group theroy? It is usually taught within the first 3-4 hours of teaching group theory.

Answer (score 0):

Any cyclic group $G$ of prime order $p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. Since any positive integer less than $p$ are relatively prime to $p$, therefore all non-identity elements can generate $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: The question here is: why being coprime with $\;p\;$ makes each of those elements a generator of the whole group? This is *what* must be proved.

Comment: @ DonAntonio yes, and for that Lagranges theorem will be of good use.